# Order relation in the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In the proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem there is an order relation so defined:

Let $S$ be the set of all pairs
$(G, u)$ where $G$ is a subspace of $E$ and indeed $F⊆G ⊆ E$ and $u$$\in$$ G^∗$
and $u(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in G$ and moreover $u|_F = f$. We define an
ordering on $S$ by $(G_1, u_1)\leq(G_2, u_2)$ if $G_1$ is a subspace of $G_2$ and
$u_2$ $|_{G_1} = u_1$.

It's a total or partial order relation?

Comment: Not  a total order. We can have pairs $(G_1,u_1),(G_1,u_1)$ that are not comparable.

Comment: I've proof reflexive and antisymmetric but for transitive?